# Do all included assets become part of built outcome or only the ones in use?

Tags: unity, assets

When building a unity game, does it include all assets inside the project folders etc or only the ones used?

Can Unity really tell if a prefab is used anywhere or a sprite or any downloaded package for that matter?

Comment: [Does this answer your question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/119907/39518)?

Comment: @DMGregory
yup, and I voted to close

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Would I need to delete unused assets from my Unity packaged build?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/119907/would-i-need-to-delete-unused-assets-from-my-unity-packaged-build)

Comment: @Kevin DMGregory already posted that, and already marked as duplicate after

Comment: @JohnDemetriou Yes, obviously I missed DMGregory's comment or I wouldn't have repeated him.

Comment: @Kevin and I already missed that this question was asked and asked a new one. It's al la circle. The circle of questions :)